# How to disable button and change color if the time is expire

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
include 'security.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'halcondentalclinic');
if (isset($_GET['date'])) {
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from bookings where dates = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $date);
    $bookings = array();
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $bookings[] = $row['timeslot'];
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
}

$duration = 30;
$cleanup = 00;
$start = "9:00";
$end = "16:00";
function timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end)
{
    $start = new DateTime($start);
    $end = new DateTime($end);
    $interval = new DateInterval("PT" . $duration . "M");
    $cleanupinterval = new DateInterval("PT" . $cleanup . "M");
    $slots = array();
    for ($intStart = $start; $intStart < $end; $intStart->add($interval)->add($cleanupinterval)) {
        $endPeriod = clone $intStart;
        $endPeriod->add($interval);
        if ($endPeriod > $end) {
            break;
        }
        $slots[] = $intStart->format("H:iA") . "-" . $endPeriod->format("H:iA");
    }

    return $slots;
}

?>
```

**html and php**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Book for Date: <?php echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date)); ?></h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : ""; ?>

        </div>
        <?php $timeslots = timeslots($duration, $cleanup, $start, $end);
        foreach ($timeslots as $ts) {

            ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php if (in_array($ts, $bookings)) { ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger"><?php echo $ts; ?></button>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <button class="btn btn-success book"
                                data-timeslot="<?php echo $ts; ?>"><?php echo $ts; ?></button>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>

            </div>
            <?php

        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]
This is the appointment system I want if the date is already past the button for the calendar time change to red and become disabled. For example, 9:00 am - 9:30 am so if the date is already 12:00 pm the 9:00 am - 9:30 become disabled

It is possible to do it? Sorry I am a beginner in PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not Php developer but as I see you can define a php function to check time is past

```
function isPastTime($time){
 // check $time is past
}
```

And when you render view, you can add class to remark `past` booking

```
<?php if(isPastTime){ ?>

<button class="btn btn-past"><?php echo $ts;?></button>
.btn-past {
  color: red;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

It is my advise. Hope you can resolve it.